# Is it possible to use ImageConvolve with Stride setting?

Tags: image-processing

```
img=Image[{{3,1,2,1,1},{3,1,1,1,1},{3,2,1,1,2},{2,2,2,2,2},{1,3,3,1,1}}]

r0=ImageConvolve[img, {{1,2,1},{2,3,2},{1,2,1}}]

r1=ImageConvolve[img, {{1,2,1},{2,3,2},{1,2,1}},Padding->0]
```

Something like this, but Stride is not a valid option now.

```
r2=ImageConvolve[img, {{1,2,1},{2,3,2},{1,2,1}},Padding->0,Stride->2]
```

I want to use `ImageConvolve` function to obtain r2 with dimension 3x3, is it possible?
Without stride setting, r2 is 5x5 size.

Comment: What is the `Stride` option? I can't find it in the docs. Could you provide the desired output as well?

Comment: Do you mean `Padding -> None` ?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, I hope it have this option.

Comment: @BenIzd. Yes, but I want it has a Padding

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation with `BlockMap` which works with arrays:

```
BlockMap[Total[# * kernel, 2] &, ArrayPad[data, 2], Dimensions[kernel], 3]
```

You have to define the `kernel` and `data` variables before running the code.

`BlockMap` Arguments:

1. The function to apply, just change the kernel
2. Padded data, use `ArrayPad` to add padding, it could be symmetric or asymmetric
3. The dimension of the kernel, don't change it
4. The Stride, can be the same number for both dimensions or specified for each

For images, you have to apply it on each channel. You can use `ImageData[ ... , Interleaving -> False]`.